# MobX class store vs functional store

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-react-lite

What is the difference between Mobx 6 class store vs functional store?

class store

```
export class UserStore {
    username;
    role;

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this)
    }
}
```

function store

```
const store = useLocalObservable(() => ({
    username: null,
    role: null,
}));
```